# Find the area of a trefoil within a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, area

[image]

Find the area. ( pls. Pls. Can you pls. allow me to delete the image.)

Comment: Anonymous, do not deface the question by removing essential parts of it. That is rude to the other users who went thru the trouble to help you. The question is not your property in the sense that you could do with it what you wish. By posting you granted the site the decision to keep it or trash it (by popular vote and site criteria).

Comment: Read what [the fine print says](http://stackexchange.com/legal). The section about Subscriber Content is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: draw a hexagon with vertices in the centers of smaller circles. What is the length of its sides? What is the distance from the center of hexagon to its vertices? Can you find $R$ now?

Answer (score 0):

The area of a hexafoil is equal to the area of the hexagon plus the area of two third of six circles.
[image]